# Reference for a formula of Kloosterman sum (in connection with Jacobi symbol) and its generalizations

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

The following is from wikipedia:

*The lifting formulas below, however, are often as good as an explicit evaluation. If $gcd(a,p) = 1$ one also has the important transformation:
$$S(a,a;p) = \sum_{m=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{m^2-4a^2}{p}\right) e^{\frac{2\pi i m}{p}},$$ where $\left(\tfrac{\ell}{m}\right)$ denotes the Jacobi symbol.*

I am looking for the reference of this formula.

I am also looking for similar formulas for other Kloosterman sums ( higher dimensions).

Comment: This one's easy enough to reconstruct an argument without a reference:
For how many $x$ is $m = ax + ax^{-1}$?  
This gives a quadratic equation with discriminant $m^2-4a^2$, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your first request on a reference for the formula:

This can be found in several places, but [here is one](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1945-51-06/S0002-9904-1945-08356-6/S0002-9904-1945-08356-6.pdf) where its online with an easy access. The paper is by Albert L. Whiteman, *A note on Kloosterman sums,* Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 51 (1945), 373--377. It has derivations as well.